# Russian taxes with dual citizenship

Tags: united-states, taxes, citizenship, russia

I'm a minor (17) who is considering using my birthright to be recognized as a Russian citizen, as my mother is one. If I apply as a minor this late, will I have to worry about taxes if I reside in the US?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in luck - only 2 countries are regressive enough to tax you based on your citizenship regardless of where you live / where you earn your income, and you're in one of them. Apart from the US, only Eritrea taxes based on citizenship.

Comment: Doesn't sound very lucky.

Comment: Based on citizenship as in they will tax regardless of residency? For example, if I lived in Russia, the US will still be able to tax me, but not the other way around, correct?

Comment: @AndrewFluck Correct. [With some exceptions - for example if you have Russian-sourced income, such as from consulting work you still do in Russia, then yes, you could be taxed on that income in Russia, even if you live in the US]. Although if you lived in Russia as a US citizen, your Russian-sourced income, such as a regular job in Russia, would be taxed in Russia first, then the US, and [to be simplistic] you would be able to reduce your US taxes owing by claiming your Russian taxes paid as 'foreign tax credits'.

Comment: Okay, that makes a lot of sense, thank you for clarifying further!